# I want to bring my inflated layout to the next line according to the screen size of the device

Tags: android, android-layout

hi I am inflating my layout with a view on every button click.But after adding 3 views the view goes out of screen and not coming to the next line.
I want my view to come to the next line according to the screen size

below is my code :

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

 notes_container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.notes_container);

 final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_note, null);

if (notes_container.getChildCount() == 0) {
        notes_container.addView(view);
    } else if (notes_container.getChildCount() < 100) {
        notes_container.addView(view, notes_container.indexOfChild(view));
    }
```

//Layout

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/notes_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5Osd.png)

Comment: Try changing your LinearLayout for a recyclerview

Comment: No ..actually its a pretty straight forward thing.Just have to add a view everytime on button click.

Comment: So change your LinearLayout for another kind of layout, like gridLayout for example, but with a LinearLayout horizontal you cannot add an element to the next line

Comment: even for grid it is not working as then i need to define row and adding to row dynamically will be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like dynamically increased 'height' is creating problem to you.

try with `android:layout_height="match_parent"`if that is not impacting your design

Comment: still the same issue.